# Do browsers translate HSL to RGB by default in the background?

Tags: html, css, browser, colors

Do browsers by default translate any color value that is not in RGB like HSL to RGB by default when displaying the color? I did put a hsl color value for the color property in css and when I did inspect the value was hsl, but I did read online how there may be some indirectly translation happening for browser to use RGB value, so thought to ask here. Is there a reason why if the browser does it, anything to do with the display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi welcome to stack overflow, as per the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color):

> If the value is translucent, the computed value will be the rgba()
> corresponding one. If it isn't, it will be the rgb() corresponding
> one.

Meaning that no matter what is your input, the computed value always results in either rgb or rgba. And it has no thing to do with the display.

Comment: so even if the color value is a named color value, the value will be rgb indirectly? @evara killer

Comment: Is there a reason why it always defaults to rgb or rgba? @evara killer

Comment: @fahidmo For your first question check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors, I think it is just to use single color format.

Comment: @fahidmo the named colors are pre defined by browsers so if a named color is given it will be converted in background but not displayed.